# Zf2 define child layout for entire module

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

I want to create a navigation for Application module as the main navigation containing all module, and a navigation for each others modules containing all controllers of this module.

It will rendered at the last like tabs with subs tabs depending of the active page.

I want to do this with child layout, without inserting `$view->layout()->addchild(..)` in each action of each controllers of each module.

Answer (score 0):

In each Module's Module.php file you can attach a custom event in the onBootstrap method to set whichever template you wanted:

```
//Attached in the onBootstrap method of Module.php
 public function determineLayoutEvent(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event) {
        $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('custom/custom_layout');
        $event->setViewModel($view);
}
```

I would do something like that^^.

There might be a hiccup or two with the code I've given when appending the actual view from the controller, but this should be a decent start.